# Are questions about mathematical "talks" on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Mathematical talks are closely related to mathematical teaching in some aspects. There are useful common points which can help both researchers and teachers to present their works and teaching materials better. Also it seems one can interpret a research level mathematical talk as a part of mathematical education. Personally I think this forum could be more useful and attractive for professional mathematicians if we let them to discuss on subjects which are useful to present a good mathematical lecture in seminars and conferences.

**Question.** Are questions about mathematical presentation/conferences on-topic here?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55385/public-speaking?referrer=N5NysswNqjESfxR8bGRmtA2).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks for the link. It seems there is a proposal for a SE presentation forum but here I mean educational aspects of math lectures. I am a bit confused about the situation. Are such questions on-topic/off-topic here?

Answer (score 3):

I think, there are two possibilities when you want to give a mathematical presentation. Either the purpose is for teaching or it is for research. For talks of the first purpose, I think this is the right site. For talks of the latter reason, I cannot imagine a question which makes sense on this site here: The question can be something general about talks, then acadamia.SE would be the right place; or the question could be something like "How can I explain the following thing I did in my paper?", then MO is maybe the right place, since it is likely that nobody here can tell you about.

If you have a certain question in your mind, post them and we can discuss about it.